# What is $R_\min$ in this formulat for optimal buffer size?

Tags: computer-networks

I read a question from my recitation about optimal buffer size. As solution there is a furmula for calculating the optimal buffer size; I'm not sure about one of its parameters. The formula is

$\quad \operatorname{Buffer}_{\text{optimal}} =  \frac{\operatorname{Buffer}_{\text{current}}}{1-\frac{R_{\text{app}}}{R_{\min}}}$

Where

- $\operatorname{Buffer}_{\text{optimal}}$ is the optimal buffer size we want to calculate.
- $\operatorname{Buffer}_{\text{current}}$ is the current buffer size.
- $R_{\text{app}}$ is the rate the application reads data from the buffer at.
- $R_{\min}$ -- this is the one I'm not sure about.

The example problem is this:

> Alice connects to web server and downloads a file of 12KB size from
>   the server. There is a router between them. The transmission rate 
>   between Alice and router is 400,000B/s and the transmission rate between 
>   router and server is 1MB/s. Buffer size in the router is 4KB, and buffer 
>   size in Alice is 3KB. The rate the application reads from Alice buffer with
>   is 100KBps.
>   [image] 
>   Calculate the optimal buffer size for Alice as a fuction of router buffer
>   size and free space at the buffer.

So as described in the solution, according to the above formula the solution is

$\qquad \operatorname{Buffer}_{\text{optimal}} = \frac{3*10^3}{1-\frac{10^5}{4*10^5}}$

So what $ R_{\min} $ could be  ?

Comment: Have you asked your teachers? It may be the minimal transissmison rate on the path between Alice and the server, though. I don't see how the solution fulfills the part with "function of [...[ free space at the buffer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R_{min}$ is the "***Writing Rate in Application Buffer***" (from router in your example).

This formula makes sense for different conditions like **$R_{app}=R_{min}$**. In this case the buffer size should be infinite (very large buffer) and it is intuitively correct. **$R_{app} >R_{min}$** makes the size negative which shows that buffering does not help while the reading data is very faster than buffering data in user side.